# How to add a ListField in djongo models?

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I want to add a ListField in my models using djongo models. Using Djongo's ListField is throwing an error while trying to update the fields from the admin site.

```
    keyword = models.TextField()
    domains = models.ListField()
    crawl_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'keywords'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather store the data as a string, and manipulate the data with some code to appear as list. Is it important to be stored as a list? Maybe not.

Comment: there are multiple domains for each keyword. They need to be stored as a list.

Comment: There is a similar case in another DB which stores a list of replies as well.